# Why is a hard drive with no remaining spare sectors considered "broken"?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

This is more of a theoretical question than a practical one. I am aware that in most (all?) cases, when a hard drive displays signs of trouble then the rational thing to do is to replace it.

From what I have gathered, when a hard drive runs out of spare sectors, it is considered "broken". Why is this so? Could it not simply continue working but with less storage capacity, just disallowing access to all broken sectors?

UPDATE: So in light of the comments, it seems the following is what I really was wondering.

1. If a hard drive is out of spare sectors, why can we not, theoretically, reallocate some good sectors as new spare sectors and then have a perfectly good drive, just with less storage capacity? (Implementing this such that it works on the fly might be hard. As I said in a comment, perhaps we could be content with having the option to clean the drive, then reallocate some good sectors as new spare sectors and then have a perfectly working drive.)
2. Is a hard drive with no spare sectors "on its last legs"? In particular: if the solution in (1) could be implemented, would the hard drive still be more prone to "fail hard" than a hard drive with its original spare sectors remaining?

Comment: I suspect it could, but it (a) would not make as much money for hard drive vendors, (b) would be a pain in the neck to implement, as shrinking partitions is hard and (c) would be dangerous because the hard drive is already on its last legs if its at this point..

Comment: (a) Sure but depressing. (b) Yes, getting this to work on the go would likely be a hell to implement. I was thinking more like wiping the drive, then allocating some of the remaining working sectors as spare sectors, then partitioning it. (c) Why is this so?

Comment: Re (c) Bad sectors indicate hardware failure. Hardware failure almost never fixes itself and often gets worse.  If a fragment scratched off/broke, this will keep damaging the disk. If a head is out of alignment whatever caused this could recur but almost certainly won't "unoccur".  HDD space is cheap, but data is often very valuable. It would be unseemly for an expert to play fast-and-loose with it.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I have gathered, when a hard drive runs out of spare sectors, it is considered broken. Why is this so? Could it not simply continue working but with less storage capacity, just disallowing access to all broken sectors?

Do have a source for this assumption? I have never found any precise decision of "broken" for a harddrive.

You have to distinguish between reading and writing instead of using the generalized term "access".
For reading purposes spare sectors do no matter. If you read an unreadable sector you will get a read error, regardless of how many spare sectors you still have in stock.
If you write to a sector that cannot be written to, expected behaviour is that your write command is rerouted to a spare sector. If there are no spare sectors left over you will get a write error.

Getting a write error on sector level might be considered severe enough to classify the respective drive as broken.

When checking SMART parameters it really depends on your personal risk tolerance when you consider a drive as broken.

Some posters have a very high risk tolerance here on this site as they are advocating continuing use of drives that already signs of dammage.

Edit 30.8.2020 16:04 MESZ:

> what I might really be wondering is why a hard drive with no spare sectors is "on its last legs".

I had a case of a collegue of mine. A badly constructed notebook seemed to have heated up a hard drive beyond reasonable temperature. There were thousands of reallocated sectors.
Such a high dammage is a dammage indicator as other SMART parameters are.
At such high rates dammage of key metadata structures in your file system gets very likely which is equivalent to loosing information.

Comment: I had trouble finding a good and brief formulation of my question. I considered writing "broken" (that is, 'broken' within quotes) instead. In light of davidgo's comment, what I might really be wondering is why a hard drive with no spare sectors is "on its last legs".